# Table does not fit

Tags: tables

I have put this into LaTeX to get a table in another page:

```
\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c ||l | l |l | l | l |l | l |l|l |l |l |l | l|l |}
\hline
Interval & \begin{sideways} Unison & Minor 2nd & Major 2nd & Minor 3rd & Major 3rd & Perfect 4th & Diminished 5th & Augmented 4th & Perfect 5th & Minor 6th and Major 6th & Minor 7th & Major 7th & Octave \end{sideways} \\
\hline
Ratios & $\frac{1}{1}$ &  $\frac{256}{243}$ &  $\frac{9}{8}$ &  $\frac{32}{27}$ &  $\frac{81}{64}$ &  $\frac{4}{3}$ &  $\frac{1024}{729}$ &  $\frac{729}{512}$ &  $\frac{3}{2}$ &  $\frac{128}{81}$ &  $\frac{27}{16}$ &  $\frac{16}{9}$ &  $\frac{243}{128}$ &  $\frac{2}{1}$ \\
\hline
Note & C & D\$flat$ & D & E\$flat$ & E & F & G\$flat$ & F$\sharp$& G & A\$flat$ & A & B\$flat$ & B & C \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The Pythagorean Chromatic Scale$}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}
}
```

But I keep getting error messages. Is it because it is too big?!

Comment: What error messages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  A tip: indenting lines by 4 spaces displays them as code.  Tables that are too big produces warnings, not errors.  Can you tell exactly what is being reported.

Comment: You should always post a complete document that shows the error and paste the _exact_ error message but this is an error with an un-matched math delimiter: `E\$flat$ `   `\$` typesets a `$` then `$` starts math mode which is never ended. also `\begin{sideways} ` is started in one cell and not ended.

Comment: I have corrected the E$\flat$ error!

Comment: The error now is Overfull \hbox (6.40596pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 166--166
[]$\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ([])[]$|

Comment: *warning, sorry

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Georgina: Please edit your question to include that information instead of burying it in comments.

Answer (score 3):

Such a table is very awkward to read: you have it sideways and the column headers are sideways too.

It's better to transpose it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
Interval & Ratio & Note \\
\midrule
Unison & $\frac{1}{1}$ & C \\
\addlinespace
Minor 2nd & $\frac{256}{243}$ & D$\flat$ \\
\addlinespace
Major 2nd & $\frac{9}{8}$ & D \\
\addlinespace
Minor 3rd & $\frac{32}{27}$ & E$\flat$ \\
\addlinespace
Major 3rd & $\frac{81}{64}$ & E \\
\addlinespace
Perfect 4th & $\frac{4}{3}$ & F \\
\addlinespace
Diminished 5th & $\frac{1024}{729}$ & G$\flat$ \\
\addlinespace
Augmented 4th & $\frac{729}{512}$ & F$\sharp$ \\
\addlinespace
Perfect 5th & $\frac{3}{2}$ & G \\
\addlinespace
Minor 6th & $\frac{128}{81}$ & A$\flat$ \\
\addlinespace
Major 6th & $\frac{27}{16}$ & A \\
\addlinespace
Minor 7th & $\frac{16}{9}$ & B$\flat$ \\
\addlinespace
Major 7th & $\frac{243}{128}$ & B \\
\addlinespace
Octave & $\frac{2}{1}$ & C \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{The Pythagorean Chromatic Scale}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code, at least as posted, contains a lot of errors and does not compile. I've tried to clean it up as best I could. Among other things, I've gotten rid of all vertical lines; IMHO vertical lines provide mostly clutter. I've also replaced various `\hline` instructions with `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`, three commands of the `booktabs` package that produce better spacing. One problem that does *not* seem to be present, though, is that of the table being too wide to fit into the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\newcommand{\rot}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}} % shorthand macro to rotate items by 90 degrees
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l *{14}{c} }
\toprule
Interval & \rot{Unison} & \rot{Minor 2nd} & \rot{Major 2nd} & 
           \rot{Minor 3rd} & \rot{Major 3rd} & \rot{Perfect 4th} & 
           \rot{Diminished 5th} & \rot{Augmented 4th\ } & \rot{Perfect 5th} & 
           \rot{Minor 6th} & \rot{Major 6th} & \rot{Minor 7th} & \rot{Major 7th} & 
           \rot{Octave}  \\
\midrule
Ratio &  $\frac{1}{1}$      &  $\frac{256}{243}$ &  $\frac{9}{8}$ &
         $\frac{32}{27}$    &  $\frac{81}{64}$   &  $\frac{4}{3}$ &
         $\frac{1024}{729}$ &  $\frac{729}{512}$ &  $\frac{3}{2}$ & 
         $\frac{128}{81}$   &  $\frac{27}{16}$   &  $\frac{16}{9}$&
         $\frac{243}{128}$  &  $\frac{2}{1}$ \\[1ex]
Note & C & D$\flat$ & D & E$\flat$ & E & F & G$\flat$ & F$\sharp$& G & A$\flat$ & A & B$\flat$ & B & C \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{The Pythagorean Chromatic Scale}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```